# How do I measure battery life?

Tags: battery, monitoring

So, I am rather happy with my battery life. I just want to know how I can measure how much time I actually get out of it. All the posts about battery life and Linux/Ubuntu/etc seem to be about improving it or similar. All I want to do is measure it.

Presumably the system logs whenever I plug/unplug my power chord, whenever I suspend/resume, and whenever I turn off/reboot. It seems there should be a way of measuring how long the computer has been on battery (up to charging the computer when closed, of course).

Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With **gnome-power-statistics**.

Run in the terminal : `gnome-power-statistics`

A GUI will appear.It allows you to visualize the power consumption of laptop hardware.

[image]
[image]

See here: [MakeUseOf](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/control-power-usage-gnome-power-statistics-linux/) and here: [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gnome-power-statistics.1.html)

Alternatively you may use powerstat.

```
sudo apt-get install powerstat
```

Then run in the terminal powerstat. It will you necessary info.
See here: [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/powerstat.8.html) and here : [hecticgeek](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/powerstat-power-calculator-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: Awesome. I'm trying it out. Will report back when I see how it works.

Comment: Power Statistics is included with Ubuntu by default, no need for any Terminal commands... Just search Unity (the menu) for "power statistics".

Comment: my ``gnome-power-statistics`` don't show any units, neither ``%`` nor ``time units``, just blank! (Ubuntu 18.04)